# Prevent adding queryParams to browser history with ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I tried removing queryParams from adding to my url when I transition between routes but failed miserably. I did what was told in the docs.

In my router :

```
queryParams: {
    status: {
        refreshModel: true,
        replace: true
    },
    itemCount: {
        refreshModel: true,
        replace: true
    },
    email: {
        replace: true
    }
}
```

That didn't work.

I did this in m link-to helper as well :

```
{{#link-to 'conversations' subuser.email (query-params email=subuser.email status='opened') replace=true}}
```

... and that didn't work as well. Ember keeps adding the params to the url, any suggestions?

Edit:

I defined my params in my controller as it should be :

```
queryParams: ['status', 'itemCount', 'email'],
status: 'opened',
email: window.preloade_ajax['email'],
itemCount: 0
```

Comment: For that first snippet of code, is that in your controller or route? Some of the query param stuff goes in the controller but that should be in the route.

Comment: queryParams hash is in the route, as shown in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using both `refreshModel` and `replace`, which is not currently supported by EmberJS.

The related issue are there :

- [Query Params `replace` doesn't work if `refreshModel` is also used](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10577)
- [Route queryParams replace does not work if refreshModel is true](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11843)

I hope it will be fixed soon..

Comment: I asked this question 2 years ago ! Don't even use ember anymore :p

Comment: It's pretty sad to see the issue is still present 2 years later.. Anyway my answer will probably be useful for next readers ! :)

Comment: After a bunch of click hole linking, looks like this may be solved now with https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/15148

Answer (score 0):

It may be late, just posting as it might help someone else. If I understood your question correctly, Ember route's hook [resetController](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.15/classes/Ember.Route/methods/resetController?anchor=resetController) should help you.

```
resetController: function (controller) {
    var queryParams = controller.get('queryParams');
    queryParams.forEach(function (param) {
        controller.set(param, null);
    });
}
```